# What value does waitForElementToBeRemoved resolve to?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

The docs say that when the element disappears, the promise returned by waitForElementToBeRemoved resolves to `true` (https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#waiting-for-disappearance), but from everything I can tell in a test that I'm running, it's resolving to `undefined`.

Can anyone confirm what value the promise resolves to?

Comment: Does it matter what the value is? If it resolves at all the thing disappeared, if it times out it rejects instead. [The implementation](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/03cfef8498a5229851984c71c0d6ba8d93ff835d/src/wait-for-element-to-be-removed.js) suggests `undefined` too, since https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/pull/631.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks! I was looking for the source code to check. I just updated the version of the package so an earlier unit test that expected `true` started failing.

Comment: I think you probably shouldn't have been asserting on the returned value - the way the docs show using it, `await waitForElementToBeRemoved(...)` means the return value doesn't matter, but the test still fails if it never gets removed.

Comment: Yeah it's a sort of weird pattern my company uses because we have a linting rule that doesn't allow any tests without assertions. I could use `await` and then assert that the element isn't there, but that feels duplicative. One alternative could be to assert that `waitForElementToBeRemoved` doesn't throw perhaps.

Comment: If it's `jest/expect-expect` note you can configure it to know about expectations other than just `expect(...)...`, see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit-ts/blob/f3a5624d0d5551103d94dcdc0b0ef5b3dc143797/.eslintrc.json#L25-L34, https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/master/docs/rules/expect-expect.md

Answer (score 0):

Credit to `@jonrsharpe` for the comment above - it seems like the docs haven't been updated. It used to resolve to `true` but now resolves to `undefined`:

https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/commit/418581fe6a2bb3ad5d569e5721583246c712fcff